# How do I use the "from" address specified in the application configuration file to send smtp message in .net?

Tags: c#, smtp, configuration-files

I specified "from" address in the application configuration file in the from section of the system.net>mailSetttings>smtp tag.

However, I apparently have to specify the "from" address in the code in the MailMessage constructor, too. When I do it in the code the address from the code overwrites the address from the configuration file.
What should I do that the "from" address from the configuration file be used? Using null or empty string causes exceptions.

Code:

```
MailMessage notificationMessage = new MailMessage(/*cannot be  null or empty here!*/null, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = messageBodyText,
    IsBodyHtml = false,
    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write proxy class in mail messages and in this class you can hardcode default from value :) simple and ugly solution but very easy :)

Comment: I'm looking for something more elegant and lazy, otherwise I could just use a custom collection in the configuration file . After all - what is this "from" attribute for if you cannot use it? :)

Comment: "From" has been a default value for e.g. "Empty@empty.xyz" and this parameter can be a last in constructor and can be a optional :) but yes this resolve solution is very ugly and must be a tag todo :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
//use the constructor without parameters        
MailMessage notificationMessage = new MailMessage()
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = messageBodyText,
    IsBodyHtml = false,
    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
};
//add the To address later
notificationMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
//from not specified, the default value from the app/web.config will be used.
```